# Creating a Query from another query

Tags: php, mysql

Looking for a little assistance..
I am trying to create a query to use as a parameters for another query.

Here is what I am attempting..

**I think I didnt make myself clear enough (big surprise)
ignore any hard coded data in the queries, they first part is using variables sent in from the search page.**

**The second query is what I really need to know how to accomplish.
If I have to figure out how to generate the sql for selecting however many records i got in the first query,,,**

```
SELECT distinct Invoice_Number   FROM invoices_details where check_number = '9999' and taxid = '9999999'
```

Which returns 3 invoice numbers..

What I need to do is to use those invoice numbers in another select...

```
***Select claim_details from claim_d where invoice in ('xxxx','yyyy','zzzz')***
```

I am at a loss on if this is even possible..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: yes it can be used inside the where in clause

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap that `SELECT` in your `IN` clause which is also known as subquery like

```
Select claim_details 
from claim_d 
where invoice in (
SELECT Invoice_Number   
 FROM invoices_details 
 where check_number = '9999' 
 and taxid = '9999999'
)
```

(OR) using a `INNER JOIN` like below (recommended approach)

```
select distinct claim_details 
from claim_d c
join invoices_details i ON c.invoice = i.Invoice_Number
where i.check_number = '9999' 
and i.taxid = '9999999';
```

Comment: I'd recommend removing `distinct` from the subquery, but other than that, looks good...

Comment: Well, with a `join`, you might need `distinct` on the outer query depending on how many rows are in the `invoice_details` table... I actually generally recommend `exists`, but there are subtle differences in all 3 approaches.  Either way, correct answer for this question!

Comment: Ok. I'd still get rid of the first query though. (And the inverted commas)

Comment: @Strawberry, don't think that would be a good idea since that's what was the original question of OP. But hey yes, edited post again to mention that `JOIN` would be recommended way to go.

Comment: Well, I guess we can agree to disagree, and I accept that both queries are valid, and it's not like you need the votes ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry, LOL ... that's counted as threatening :)

Comment: I edited my original question, I didnt make myself clear

Comment: @KDriscoll perhaps you should try editing again - this answer still seems like it answers the question.